# Swing GridBagLayout anchor is outside of the window

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm playing around with `GridBagLayout` in Swing and I noticed the anchor point on the left is correct, but the one at the top is at -60 pixels. I know the exact size of the window, 960x640. I'm making two columns: one with two panels on the left (grid heights are 2 for both) and another with three panels on the right (grid heights are 1, 2 and 1). This is the code:

```
    gameFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

    InfoPanel infoPanel = new InfoPanel();
    infoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
    infoPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
    infoPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
    infoPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    //constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 2;

    gameFrame.add(infoPanel, constraints);


    InfoPanel infoPanel2 = new InfoPanel();
    infoPanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
    infoPanel2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
    infoPanel2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
    infoPanel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    //constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 2;

    gameFrame.add(infoPanel2, constraints);


    InfoPanel infoPanel3 = new InfoPanel();
    infoPanel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 200));
    infoPanel3.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 200));
    infoPanel3.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(640, 200));
    infoPanel3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    //constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;

    gameFrame.add(infoPanel3, constraints);


    InfoPanel infoPanel4 = new InfoPanel();
    infoPanel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 240));
    infoPanel4.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 240));
    infoPanel4.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(640, 240));
    infoPanel4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    //constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 2;

    gameFrame.add(infoPanel4, constraints);


    InfoPanel infoPanel5 = new InfoPanel();
    infoPanel5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 200));
    infoPanel5.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 200));
    infoPanel5.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(640, 200));
    infoPanel5.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    //constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    //constraints.gridheight = 1;

    gameFrame.add(infoPanel5, constraints);

    gameFrame.pack();
    gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

I appreciate that the code isn't clean, it's not what it will look like, I just wanted to make sure I can get the layout I need working first.

Here is the result:
[image: GridBagLayout]

Because the layout starts placing objects at -60 pixels off the top, there's a 60 pixel gap at the bottom.

Has anyone come across something like this? It baffles me.

Comment: I'm hoping it's for test purposes, but just in case, [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the info, I was never sure why doing this was frowned upon, but I knew it's not recommended, and now I have an explanation. But yes, the reason I'm trying with all three is due to my desperation :)

Comment: I can make it work, but I can't explain why you have extra space at the end of the frame...

Comment: I think this is one of those moments that that layout manager has thrown it's arms up in the air and said, "Well, that's the best I can do with what you've given me".  If you change `constraints.gridheight = 2;` to `constraints.gridheight = 3;` for `infoPanel2` it'll work.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, that did the trick like you said. I'll be happy marking this as the accepted answer should you choose to post it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is one of those moments that that layout manager has thrown it's arms up in the air and said, *"Well, that's the best I can do with what you've given me"*.

If you change `constraints.gridheight = 2;` to `constraints.gridheight = 3;` for `infoPanel2` it'll work.

I *"think"* it has a combination of things to do with the total height of the second column when compared to the first (without consideration to the row spanning).  Allowing the second row to expand beyond the the two rows seems to allow it to collapse the extra space.

For what it's worth.  I would have probably put the two columns into individual panels and laid out those two panels instead, but that's just me...